# How can I map data from a firestore database in a useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, async-await, use-effect

I'm trying to get some data from a firestore database and save it into a array in react. This is my code.

```
    const readDocuments = async () => {          
        const allData = await getDocs(collectionRef);
        //console.log(allData);
        // allData.forEach((doc) => {
        //     console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
        // });
        setData(allData.docs.map((doc) => ({
            ...doc.data(), id: doc.id
        })))
        console.log(data);
        //return allData;
    };
```

When I check the console, this is what I get.

[image]

Not really sure what I'm doing wrong here. I saw pretty much the same method used in a tutorial. And if I uncomment the foreach loop within the function, it outputs the data properly so I figure it's not a issue with actually retrieving the information.

Edit: The function above is nested in a useEffect hook.

Comment: It will be better if you will post the entire page. I wish to help but I don't understand where is your fetch and how you extract the data.
Especially "getDocs" if you are using this as a hook.

Comment: @ZurielS.G. Thank you for the response. There is no fetch that I've written. There should be a fetch or some sort of method that firebase uses to retrieve the data but as far as I'm aware, it doesn't need me to manually write a fetch method. The 'getDocs' is also a function that firebase provides to get data from the database. I can post the rest of the code if you wish but there's very little else on the file other than the useEffect hook nesting the entire readDocuments function and the readDocuments function being called in the next line.

Comment: Please add getDocs(collectionRef) function to your post. and did you check if the this function return any err?

Comment: Always glad to help :) 
 https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/get-data  

Got it, so what is collectionRef?   You should also assign the data to a useState rather than a useRef
What is the resould from console logging allData?

Comment: @ZurielS.G.Not a very satisfying answer but I started a project from scratch and started from scratch and it seems to work now. If I had to guess I'd say I had an issue with creating a custom hook which is why the data wasn't being read. Thank you both for your responses. Appreciate it a lot!

Comment: @yanirmidler Not a very satisfying answer but I started a project from scratch and started from scratch and it seems to work now. If I had to guess I'd say I had an issue with creating a custom hook which is why the data wasn't being read. Thank you both for your responses. Appreciate it a lot!

Comment: if your issue is resolved can you post your answer to the changes you made in the custom hook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase/config";

const useGetDocs = (collectionName) => {
    const [documents, setDocuments] = useState([]);

    //Firebase Collection Reference
    const postCollectionRef = collection(db, collectionName);

    useEffect(() => {
        const getDocuments = async () => {
            const data = await getDocs(postCollectionRef);
            setDocuments(data.docs.map((doc) => ({...doc.data(), id: doc.id})));
        };

        getDocuments();
    }, []);

    return { documents };
}
 
export default useGetDocs;
```

This is the full file that I used and it works now. Not necessarily sure what was wrong before but the main change I made was created it as a custom hook using the 'use' keyword which might have had something to do with it. I'm no expert by any means and could still be doing something wrong but hopefully this helps someone if they have a similar issue.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data?hl=en&authuser=0#web-version-9_1) they are showing you exactly how to do it.

```
import { collection, query, where, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore";

const q = query(collection(db, "cities"), where("capital", "==", true));

const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
  console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
});
```

Comment: Hey mate. The issue wasn't within getting the data back itself but on how to map and save the data into a local variable in an Array. Thank you for taking the time to look it up!